# How to disjoint xml file

Tags: xml

I am looking for a python script (or even an easier option) to disjoint xml file.

Input xml has this format

```
*<config>
<block1>
..
</block1>
<block2>
..
</block2>
<block3>
..
</block3>
<block4>
..
</block4>
</config>*
```

This has to be split into four blocks

block1.xml will contain this part-

```
*<config>
<block1>
..
<block1>
</config>*
```

block2.xml will contain this part-

```
*<config>
<block2>
..
<block2>
</config>*
```

so on..

Would you please share/ give an idea how to do this?

Thanks in advance,

Best regards,
Ashish

Comment: Using XSLT-2.0 with `result-document` this could be achieved easily.

Comment: Would you be able to share a sample code to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="config">
    <xsl:for-each select="*[starts-with(name(),'block')]">
      <xsl:result-document href="{name()}.xml">
        <config>
          <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </config>
      </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
     
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works for a simple file; but does not work for large file (18MB)..Looks like we need to set the exact tag instead of starts with name.

Comment: Great, what exactly is the problem with a large file. Non unique file-names maybe?
Let me know if you succeed.

Comment: Input file:
<config xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">
<interfaces xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-interfaces" xmlns:ianaift="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:iana-if-type">
<interface>
<name>interface1</name>
<description>interface1</description>
<type>ianaift:ethernetCsmacd</type>
<ipv4 xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-ip">
<address>
<ip>192.168.1.1</ip>
<prefix-length>28</prefix-length>
</address>
</ipv4>
<routing-instance xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-routing">interface1</routing-instance>
</interface>
</interfaces>
</config>

Comment: output that I got is like this-   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


interface1
interface1
ianaift:ethernetCsmacd


192.168.1.1
28


interface1

Comment: xslt file - <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="config">
    <xsl:for-each select="*[starts-with(name(),'interfaces')]">
      <xsl:result-document href="{name()}.xml">
        <config>
          <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </config>
      </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
     
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: @Ashish: What would like to have as result? One interface in every xml or one interfaces in every xml.
Better would be to change your question with an example that resamples this data and also to show your expected result.

Comment: Hi, "interfaces" tag contain multiple child named "interface" tag. In the original file, there are around 17 other tags which contains many more child elements. The objective is to split the input xml into multiple xml by selecting all child elements under the tag with depth=1 for example interfaces tag in the above example.

Comment: @Ashish: I'm not gonna solve your complete problem. This answer was the result to your question. If you want to know more about xslt, do some training and searching yourself. Also take a look on how to handle namespaces.
If you get stock, share your source and desired outcome and current xslt in a new question. Success

Comment: Thanks a lot! Looking forward to your final answer. My bad-I didn't predict that namespace can cause issue. By the way, I have started learning xslt.

Comment: @Ashish: As stated before, if you want me to help you, start a new question with a good enough source, self tried xslt and expected outcome. Succes with learning xslt. It's the best language for handling xml.

Comment: Here is the new post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67460611/disjoint-xml-file-with-namespace