# disjoint xml file with namespace

Tags: xml, split

I am looking for help to disjoint a xml file with namespace=

***Input file:***

```
<config xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0"> 
<interfaces xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-interfaces" xmlns:ianaift="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:iana-if-type">
    <interface> 
        <name>interface1</name> 
        <description>interface1</description> 
        <type>ianaift:ethernetCsmacd</type> 
        <ipv4 xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-ip"> 
            <address> 
                <ip>192.168.1.1</ip> 
                <prefix-length>28</prefix-length> 
            </address> 
        </ipv4> 
        <routing-instance xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-routing">interface1</routing-instance> 
    </interface> 
    <interface> 
        <name>interface2</name> 
        <description>interface2</description> 
        <type>ianaift:ethernetCsmacd</type> 
        <ipv4 xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-ip"> 
            <address> 
                <ip>192.168.1.2</ip> 
                <prefix-length>28</prefix-length> 
            </address> 
        </ipv4> 
        <routing-instance xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-routing">interface2</routing-instance> 
    </interface>     
</interfaces>
<routing xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-routing">
    <name/>
</routing>
</config>
```

output will contain all entries under the interfaces tag as is.

Regards,
Ashish

Comment: Show at least also the name and the content of one target.xml

Comment: And show what you did until now to accomplish this

Comment: Expected output would contain whole input xml except the below part - <routing xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-routing">
    <name/>
</routing>

Comment: In the meantime, I have been able to achieve the objective using python along with a sed script. With python script, got the tag information and then used sed to crop the expected output. However, there is manual work in this approach. I am looking forward to get the xslt based solution from you. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can use python, you don't need sed. You can just use an XML parser and extract the `<interfaces>` node and its two `<interface>` child nodes.

Comment: Hi Jack, Would you please the example code how to do this using python xml parser?

Comment: Sure; see answer below.

Comment: Hi, Thanks, Can we use the xml file as input?

Comment: Sure; use `etree.parse("file.xml")`. See https://lxml.de/parsing.html.

Comment: Thanks! It's working now. Great!

Comment: Great! If we're done, don't forget to accept the answer, please.

Comment: No worries. I have a last question. In the input file, I have two tags/elements called interfaces and routing. How can I identify those and pass those as variable to doc.xpath ()

Comment: I don't know, since I have no access to the xml file. If it's important, best to post it as a separate question, per SO policy.

Comment: Hi, Input file is in the initial post.

Comment: root= doc.getroot()
for child in root:
    filtertag=root.findall(child.tag)
    print (filtertag)

output-

[<Element {urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-interfaces}interfaces at 0x1c207e03688>]
[<Element {urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-routing}routing at 0x1c207e037c8>]

Comment: Now, need to take the tag/element name from this printout to pass to doc.xpath (). Not sure how can I do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you would do it with python, using lxml as the xml parser:

```
from lxml import etree
inter  = """[your xml above]"""
doc = etree.XML(inter)

target = doc.xpath('//*[local-name()="interfaces"]')
print(etree.tostring(target[0]).decode())
```

Output:

```
<interfaces xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-interfaces" xmlns:ianaift="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:iana-if-type">
    <interface> 
        <name>interface1</name> 
        <description>interface1</description> 
        <type>ianaift:ethernetCsmacd</type> 
        <ipv4 xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-ip"> 
            <address> 
                <ip>192.168.1.1</ip> 
                <prefix-length>28</prefix-length> 
            </address> 
        </ipv4> 
        <routing-instance xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-routing">interface1</routing-instance> 
    </interface> 
    <interface> 
        <name>interface2</name> 
        <description>interface2</description> 
        <type>ianaift:ethernetCsmacd</type> 
        <ipv4 xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-ip"> 
            <address> 
                <ip>192.168.1.2</ip> 
                <prefix-length>28</prefix-length> 
            </address> 
        </ipv4> 
        <routing-instance xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-routing">interface2</routing-instance> 
    </interface>     
</interfaces>
```